# sort list items alphabetically without salutation

Tags: jquery

I want to sort my list items(person names) alphabetically, only name should sort but not salutation(Mr. Mrs. Shri etc..)

There are 5 fixed salutations coming from DB. (Shri Sh. Mr. Ms. Mrs.)

Is this possible to achieve through jQuery?

I have this code:

```
<ul class='list1'>
   <li>Mr. Brwon</li>
   <li>Shri D.K. Miller</li>
   <li>Mrs. F. Jhon</li>
   <li>Shri Candy Joe</li>
   <li>Mr. E Ram</li>
   <li>Mrs. Andrew G</li>
</ul>
```

The result should be:

Mrs. Andrew G

Mr. Brwon

Shri Candy Joe

Shri D.K. Miller

Mr. E Ram

Mrs. F. Jhon

Comment: Do you have a list of all the possible salutations? Or can we assume that the salutations are always the first word?

Comment: yes.. there will be 3-4 salutations.

Comment: Are these names coming from a server? If so, I would do the sort there

Comment: yes, these are coming from DB

Comment: These are the fixed salutations coming from DataBase.
Shri
Sh.
Mr.
Ms.
Mrs.

Comment: Are Shri and Sh two separate salutations? Or one with two words?

Comment: both are separate, one is Sh.  another is Shri

Answer (score 0):

```js
var salutations = ["Shri", "Sh.", "Mr.", "Ms.", "Mrs."];

var text = [];
$(".list1").children().each(function(i, child){ 
  text.push($(child).text());
  text.sort(function(a, b){
  
      aWord = a;
      bWord = b;
    salutations.forEach(function(sal){
      aWord = aWord.replace(sal, "");
      bWord = bWord.replace(sal, "");
    });
  
    return (aWord < bWord ? -1 : 1);
   
  });
});
$(".list1").empty();
text.forEach(function(name, i){
  $(".list1").append("<li>" + name + "</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list1'>
   <li>Mr. Brwon</li>
   <li>Shri D.K. Miller</li>
   <li>Mrs. F. Jhon</li>
   <li>Shri Candy Joe</li>
   <li>Mr. E Ram</li>
   <li>Mrs. Andrew G</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: At the moment I am sorting and outputting to console. Do you need the output to resort the original list in the HTML?

Comment: Hi Joshua, some of my names are like, Mr. B. John
Mrs. A.K. Lilly

Also I need the output to resort the original list in HTML.

Comment: Take a look now

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $('ul.list1').append( $('ul.list1 li').detach().sort(function(a, b) {
        var aname = $(a).text().split(' ').pop(),
            bname = $(b).text().split(' ').pop();
        return (aname < bname ? -1 : aname > bname ? 1 : 0);
    }) );
});
```

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ynkva9a/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First take all list element text into an array, then call a sort() function to sort the array. In sort callback function you need to write your custom comparison function that will compare string based on the last name (except initials text). Then copy list back to html  element .

Try this :

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test-btn").on("click", function() {
    var list = $(".list1 li").map(function() {
      return $(this).text();
    });

    list.sort(function(a, b) {
      var a_name = a.substring(a.indexOf(" "), a.length);
      var b_name = b.substring(b.indexOf(" "), b.length);
      return a_name < b_name ? -1 : a_name > b_name ? 1 : 0;
    });
    $(".list1").empty();
    list.each(function(i, v) {
      $(".list1").append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
    });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='list1'>
  <li>Mr. Brwon</li>
  <li>Shri D.K. Miller</li>
  <li>Mrs. F. Jhon</li>
  <li>Shri Candy Joe</li>
  <li>Mr. E Ram</li>
  <li>Mrs. Andrew G</li>
</ul>

<button id="test-btn">Sort List</button>
```